# magento 2: cron to run after exception also

Tags: magento2, cron

I have created a custom module which has cronjob to run after certain interval:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <!--cron job to import customer,customer assignment,product data,pricing data and listing master-->
        <job name="import_customer_product" instance="Singh\Import\Cron\CustomerProduct" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <!--cron job to import order,invoice and shipment-->
        <job name="import_order_edi" instance="Singh\Import\Cron\OrderImport" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

There are 5 processes running for 1st cron and 3 for 2nd cron. If any exception or error comes in process 1, the cron stops and its status change to **error**, it bypass other 4 processes and execute the next cron.

Content of **`CustomerProduct.php`**:

```
public function execute() {
    $cron = $this->_cronfactory->create();
    $this->_logger->info("customer and product import cron started");
    $this->_customer->execute();
    $this->_logger->info("customer imported");
    $this->_customerAssignment->execute();
    $this->_logger->info("customer ass imported");
    $this->_product->execute();
    $this->_logger->info("product imported");
    $this->_listingMaster->execute();
    $this->_logger->info("listing imported");
    $this->_productPricing->execute();
    $this->_logger->info("pricing imported");
    $this->_logger->info("customer and product import cron finished");
}
```

**What I want is**: the cron should run the next process if it found any exception or error in 1st process, it should not bypass other process.

Comment: I think you should handle exception in your CRON process

Comment: I tried by applying exception handling, but nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs should not throw exceptions and break script execution.

Look for the exception type thrown and catch and log it. In the worst case catch \Exception and any exception will not stop script execution.

Reminder to add logger to your dependency injection.

Example using your code:

```
public function execute() {
    try {
        $cron = $this->_cronfactory->create();
        $this->_logger->info("customer and product import cron started");
        $this->_customer->execute();
        $this->_logger->info("customer imported");
        $this->_customerAssignment->execute();
        $this->_logger->info("customer ass imported");
        $this->_product->execute();
        $this->_logger->info("product imported");
        $this->_listingMaster->execute();
        $this->_logger->info("listing imported");
        $this->_productPricing->execute();
        $this->_logger->info("pricing imported");
        $this->_logger->info("customer and product import cron finished");
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```